# How to show the penultimate date per combination of two values in different columns

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using Oracle 12c, and I have a table with various column including a date column for the entry of the record. I want to make sure I get the penultimate date per item and location combination in my table.

Here is the SQL code I did to try to achieve this:

```
SELECT 
   DISTINCT 
   ITEM,
   LOCATION, 
   ORDER_POINT, 
   SAFETY_STOCK, 
   NTH_VALUE(REPL_DATE, 2) 
   OVER (PARTITION BY ITEM,LOCATION ORDER BY REPL_DATE DESC
   RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) AS PREVIOUS_DATE  
FROM 
   REPL_RESULTS
```

Here is a sample of results when I run the following:

```
SELECT 
   ITEM,
   LOCATION, 
   ORDER_POINT, 
   SAFETY_STOCK,
   REPL_DATE
FROM 
   REPL_RESULTS
ORDER BY ITEM, LOCATION
```

Results :

```
ITEM    LOCATION ORDER_POINT SAFETY_STOCK REPL_DATE 
0006296   100495    4.8416      0.1937     1/10/2019
0006296   100495    4.9021      0.2201     1/3/2019
0006296   100495    4.7848      0.15       11/22/2018
0006296   132142    3.1516      0.2481     1/9/2019
0006296   132142    2.091       0.23       1/16/2019
0006296   132142    2.903       0.1811     11/14/2018
```

The result I am expecting is this:

```
ITEM    LOCATION ORDER_POINT SAFETY_STOCK PREVIOUS_DATE 
0006296   100495    4.9021      0.2201     1/3/2019
0006296   132142    3.1516      0.2481     1/9/2019
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can use Oracle window function `ROW_NUM()` to assign a row number to each row within each item/location group ordered by repl date, and then filter on records having row number 2.

```
SELECT x.*
FROM (
    SELECT
        t.*,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY t.item, t.location ORDER BY t.repl_date desc) rn
    FROM mytable t
) x WHERE x.rn = 2
```

This **[demo on db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=c751bac7371d00b3acdc8785bc8dc3f1)** yields :

```
ITEM | LOCATION | ORDER_POINT | SAFETY_STOCK | REPL_DATE | RN
---: | -------: | ----------: | -----------: | :-------- | -:
6296 |   100495 |      4.9021 |        .2201 | 03-JAN-19 |  2
6296 |   132142 |      3.1516 |        .2481 | 09-JAN-19 |  2
```

Comment: It could be a `DENSE_RANK` instead, couldn't it?

Comment: @lau : yes, or even `RANK`. It depends on how they want to deal with duplicates... which was not explained in the OP.

Comment: Not Rank actually, as you are not guaranteed to have `value = 2` returned by `Rank` Only `value = 1` is guaranteed by `ROW_NUMBER`, `DENSE_RANK` and `RANK` altogether.